# How do I reset/clear erlang terminal

Tags: terminal, erlang, reset

I'm trying to get the prompt reset, forget all the variables and start the prompt from line 1>
I'm aware of the following built-in functions

```
f().                      %% forget all
io:format("\e[H\e[J").    %% "clear screen" and moving cursor to the begin of the line
```

but when I'm writing the following commands, it does forget all the variables, but it doesn't "reset" the screen, just clear the screen, like `clear` command in the terminal.

in Linux, I just type `reset`, but I couldn't find equivalent command or built in function for erlang to do that.

I also tried `io:format(os:cmd("reset")).`  but I received error.

my solution for now is to quit the erlang terminal, and reopen it again, but I'm sure there is much easier ways to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A somewhat *tricky* way to do it would be to just start a new shell by pressing ctrl-g and then `s`, `c`

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source-d2a6d81] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> A = 1.
1
2>
User switch command
 --> s
 --> c
Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> A.
* 1: variable 'A' is unbound
2>
```

Of course that doesn't clear the screen. You have to use your own console mechanisms for that (I use iTerm on OSX and I just hit `cmd-k` for that)

Comment: You can kill orginal shell using `k`. So it is ^G k⏎ s⏎ c⏎.

Answer (score 14):

To clear the erl shell

`io:format(os:cmd(clear)).`

Answer (score 8):

Most of the terminals you would use on a Unix-like system support the VT100 [hardware-reset](http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#RIS) escape sequence.  You could use that in your program like this:

```
io:format("\ec").
```

That is *instead* of

```
io:format("\e[H\e[J").    %% "clear screen" and moving cursor to the begin of the line
```

although it would not hurt to do both.  Also, it does not affect your variables, so you would still do

```
f().                      %% forget all
```

Combining these:

```
f().                      %% forget all
io:format("\ec").
io:format("\e[H\e[J").    %% "clear screen" and moving cursor to the begin of the line
```

should be what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

As @Brujo Benavides mentioned earlier . The way to do that is to exit the current erl shell and start a new . You can use the `halt().` function which is less tricky .

Answer (score 0):

Or do a more thorough clear. This will clear your terminal's buffer:

```
io:format("\033\143").
```

Which equals to either of the following shell commands:

```
printf "\033\143"
```

```
tput reset
```

The latter requires you have `ncurses` installed.