# How to clear the screen in erlang with Ctrl+L or similar?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Is there any why to clear the erlang screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> like shortcut?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset/clear erlang terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829916/how-do-i-reset-clear-erlang-terminal)

Comment: Is there any possibility of using Ctr-L to clear the terminal?

Comment: You can use command+k, command+L will be used to clear one line at a time.

Comment: is **command** is __Ctr__?, It's not working for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rlwrap -a erl` command.

**`rlwrap`** is completely transparent to Erlang shell in case of user character input and it wraps them with [readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) that provides line-editing and history capabilities for interactive programs with a command-line interface like `erl`.

Note that in a case of using commands like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> for name completion, `rlwrap` doesn't pass it to Erlang shell.

Comment: how can I bypass **Ctrl-G** from **rlwrap** to erlang?

Comment: @SreekanthNagareddy Unfortunately **rlwrap** doesn't let you use Erlang's job handler with **Ctrl-G**. Also it doesn't let you use tab completion.

Comment: @HamidrezaSoleimani: Which effectively disprove _completely transparent_ claim of yours.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil In case of user character input it is completely transparent, but when it come to using commands with and key bindings, no it is not. Thanks for clarifying and I made the answer clearer.

Comment: [I have extended](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/commit/bb8034e3e4b5e63162ed834082d3c8054c85eb9f) `rlwrap` to allow keypresses like CTRL-G to go directly to the rlwrapped command, bypassing the line editor. For this to work, you need to add `"\C-g": rlwrap-direct-keypress ` to `~/.inputrc` (and the latest `rlwrap` from [Github](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap), of course) This won't help with tab completion, however ([Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/is-there-a-way-of-running-rlwrap-with-tab-completion-disabled) why)